# Java Android passing data Array double

Tags: android, android-intent, double

I have a question about intent in android application

i have an array in **class1**

```
double [][] tableCityPair = new double[100][100];
```

---here code to fill array---
in the end of class i want to send tableCityPair to another class, **class2**.

how i should declare for array in class2 ?
is this right?

```
Intent it = getIntent();
double tabelJarakAntarKota= it.getDoubleExtra("tableCityPair",3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bundle` class has methods for passing and retrieving an array of `double`s:

- [`void putDoubleArray(String, double[])`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putDoubleArray%28java.lang.String,%20double%5B%5D%29)
- [`double [] getDoubleArray(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getDoubleArray%28java.lang.String%29)

However, these work for one-dimensional arrays. You are attempting to pass a 2D array. I do not know of a direct way to do this. One way to achieve this would be to put N arrays of doubles in a loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<tableCityPair.length;i++){
    bundle.put("tableCity"+i, tableCityPair[i]);
}
```

And at the receiving end, you do:

```
double [] aPair = it.getExtras().getDoubleArray("tableCity"+i);
```

I'm not sure about the performance implications of this though; since you would be adding 100 extras as part of the bundle.

There could be a better way (perhaps make your pair a `List<List<Double>>` and then implement `Parcelable`) but I haven't tried any of it so I wouldn't suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

```
double [][] tableCityPair = new double[100][100];
```

and then...
   make intent it=....
then

```
put: `it.putExtra("size",tableCityPair.length)`
```

then:

```
    for(i=0;i<tableCitypair.length;i++)
{

it.putExtra("table"+i,tableVityPair[i][]);

}
```

THEN in CLASS B

```
double [][] tableCityPairinB = new double[100][100];
for(i=0;i<getIntent().getExtras("size");i++)
{
double[i][]=getIntent().getExtras("table"+i);

}
```

Comment: The question was about passing an _array_ of doubles.

Comment: @jaisonDavis i have try that code but still error: The method getDoubleArray(String) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

Comment: did you put                                                       `double [] tabelJarakAntarKota=it.getDoubleExtra("tableCityPair",3);`