# Passing Double Array through intent passes null

Tags: android

I have the following code:
in TrackerActivity

```
ArrayList<Double> latitudes;
ArrayList<Double> longitudes;
ArrayList<Double> altitudes;

...

Intent intent = new Intent(this, SummaryActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(LATITUDES_EXTRA, latitudes.toArray());
intent.putExtra(LONGITUDES_EXTRA, longitudes.toArray());
intent.putExtra(ALTITUDES_EXTRA, altitudes.toArray());
startActivity(intent);
```

and in SummaryActivity:

```
latitudes = getIntent().getDoubleArrayExtra(TrackerActivity.LATITUDES_EXTRA);
longitudes = getIntent().getDoubleArrayExtra(TrackerActivity.LONGITUDES_EXTRA);
altitudes = getIntent().getDoubleArrayExtra(TrackerActivity.ALTITUDES_EXTRA);
```

however I get null for all of them. what could be wrong?

Comment: Please specify the types of each variable

Comment: In particular, I am not aware of a `toArray()` method anywhere that would result in `double[]`, which is [what `getDoubleArrayExtra()` returns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getDoubleArrayExtra(java.lang.String)). Most likely, your extras are something else.

Comment: and how would you send an arrayList of doubles through two activities?

Comment: putExtra(String name, Serializable value)

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bundle class has methods for passing and retrieving an array of doubles:

```
 - void putDoubleArray(String, double[])
 - double [] getDoubleArray(String)
```

may be [this ans will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10792889/5727285)

Comment: I've actually tried to use Serializable object and it works... but I like your answer so I'll mark it as the answer. Thank You!

Comment: That answer is four years old. I suggest you stay up to date, it will help you both focus on the real problems out there.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

**TrackerActivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SummaryActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(LATITUDES_EXTRA, latitudes);
intent.putExtra(LONGITUDES_EXTRA, longitudes);
intent.putExtra(ALTITUDES_EXTRA, altitudes);
startActivity(intent);
```

**SummaryActivity**

```
latitudes = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList(TrackerActivity.LATITUDES_EXTRA);
longitudes = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList(TrackerActivity.LONGITUDES_EXTRA);
altitudes = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList(TrackerActivity.ALTITUDES_EXTRA);
```

**Why does this work?**
conversion from primitives to objects is trivial in Java thanks to a feature called autoboxing, which Oracle's current documentation reads:

> > Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called unboxing.

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert each `ArraryList<Double>` to a `double[]`. The problem is that `ArraryList.toArray()` returns a `Double[]` instead. You can either declare your lists as arrays to begin with or write a little for loop to copy from a list to an array.

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: He already has an ArrayList, what's your justification for this?

Comment: @Chisko That's the problem. He needs an **array**.

Comment: No he does not. ArrayList are Serializables, and there's already a method for them

Comment: @Chisko Feel free to post your own answer to show how to do this.

Comment: @Chisko Will putSerializableExtra() maintain the type for the elements of the list?

Comment: Try my answer and let me know